# combining mod_rewrite and vhost_dbd_module

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, vhosts

I'm trying to give users a static files folder served from inside their chroot. The following code works under other conditions (basically without the inclusion of the DBDocRoot directive) but just doesn't do what is expected. Is mod_vhost_dbd simply not compatible with mod_rewrite? It partially works in that the request hits the correct python script which then does some other stuff and launches a wsgi app.

With this code nothing is logged in rewrite.log. If you comment out the DBDocRoot directive line stuff is logged but of course the rewrite rule doesn't work because ${ENV:username} is the empty string. The query work perfectly well when run from a mysql console.

```
LoadModule vhost_dbd_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_vhost_dbd.so
DBDExptime 5

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
    RewriteLogLevel 9

    DBDriver mysql
    DBDParams host=amysqlhost,user=abdbuser,pass=private,dbname=adbname
    DBDocRoot "SELECT concat('/mnt/user_storage/webscripts/', username, '/user_script.py'), username from user, userdomain where user.id = userdomain.user_id and userdomain.domain_name = %s" HOSTNAME

    RewriteCond /mnt/user_storage/homedirs/%{ENV:username}/var/www/static%{REQUEST_URI} -f
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) /mnt/user_storage/homedirs/%{ENV:username}/var/www/static/$1 [L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Has anyone else successfully used this module to set an environment variable? The notes on the [mod_vhost_dbd wiki](http://code.google.com/p/dbd-modules/wiki/mod_vhost_dbd) say that it can be done.

Comment: To answer my own question, no, what I was trying to do here is not possible.